# X legacy code with g++: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c++11

The attached code creates problems when compiled with g++ as indicated.
1) Why does const char* (and char const*) work while const String does not, where String is typdef'd to char*?
2) In the second code snippet, how to avoid the warning? I cannot change the struct XrmOptionDescRec. It is defined at X11/Xresource.h from libx11-dev.

Additional info:
The struct XrmOptionDescRec is given by the C header file, and the call is made to to the libx11-6 C library, specifically the function XtAppInitialize(). How to write the C++ code calling that function, see the second part of my code snippet.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//From: libxt-dev: /usr/include/X11/Intrinsic.h
typedef char* String;
typedef char *XPointer;

typedef enum {
  XrmoptionSepArg
} XrmOptionKind;

// From: libx11-dev: /usr/include/X11/Xresource.h
typedef struct {
  char *option;
  char *specifier;
  XrmOptionKind argKind;
  XPointer value;
} XrmOptionDescRec;

typedef struct {
  const char *option;
  const char *specifier;
  XrmOptionKind argKind;
  XPointer value;
} const_XrmOptionDescRec;

int main(void)
{
/*
Causes compiler warnings:
ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
static const String fallbackResources[] = {
*/

/* Works fine */
  static const char* fallbackResources[] = {
  "*.zoomComboBox*fontList: -*-helvetica-medium-r-normal--12-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1",
  "*XmTextField.fontList: -*-courier-medium-r-normal--12-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1",
  NULL
};
  printf ("fallbackResources[1]=%s\n",fallbackResources[1]); 

/*
Causes compiler warnings:
ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
static XrmOptionDescRec xOpts[] = {
*/
/* Works fine */
  static const_XrmOptionDescRec xOpts[] = {
  {"-display",       ".display",         XrmoptionSepArg,  NULL},
  {"-foreground",    "*Foreground",      XrmoptionSepArg,  NULL}
};
   printf ("xOpts[1]=%s, %s, %d, %p\n", xOpts[1].option, xOpts[1].specifier, xOpts[1].argKind, xOpts[1].value);
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why do you have a type-alias `String` to handle strings? Why not the standard `std::string` class? There's really not much C++ in your code, it could as easily have been compiled with a C compiler.

Comment: That type-alias is also from the X legacy code, /usr/include/X11/Intrinsic.h. The code at hand is also legacy code: xpdf, which is written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Please be noted that `const String` is not equal to `const char*`, it is `char* const` instead.

So the code:

```
typedef char* String;
const String someString = "xxx";
```

is the same as

```
char* const someString = "xxx";
```

Obviously it generates the warning, because it tells the compiler that the content of `someString` **can** be modified, while it's really a string literal and can **NOT** be modified.

Comment: `const char*` and `char const*` are identical, `char * const` is different.

Comment: And "String const" is the same as "char* const" too?

Comment: @user1914074 yes, `const String` and `String const` here are identical. You need `typedef const char* ConstString;`

Comment: Thanks, that was as I expected then. What to do in the C++ code when the struct is from a C library header, e.g.  xOPts, and that structure is passed to a C library function, e.g.  XtAppInitialize(..., xOpts,...)?

Comment: @user1914074 I don't get your question?

Comment: The struct is given by the C header file, and the call is made to to that C library. How to write the C++ code calling that function, see the second part of my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ string literals are arrays of *constant* characters. Because of this you can't have a pointer to non-constant characters (i.e. `char*`) pointing to a string literal.

If you can't change structures (like if they are defined in system header files) then you have to store your strings in (non-constant) arrays, and make the pointers point to your (non-constant) arrays.

Example

```
char modifiableString[] = "Some string here";
char* nonConstPointerToString = modifiableString;
```

Answer (score 0):

just add **const**:

```
const char* str= "some string";
```